# How to delete(or kill) the current word in emacs?

Tags: emacs

For example, my cursor (point) is at an arbitrary letter in the word "cursor". I want to delete (kill) that word such that it is copied to `kill-ring`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good fit for StackOverflow.  You might get a better answer at Unix or Programmers.

Comment: Where in "cursor" do you see any "x"?

Comment: @TrippKinetics: Or even http://emacs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @choroba Ah.  I didn't know about that one.  Thanks.

Comment: yes, "x" letter is any letter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use this as a framework for killing various kinds of things at point:

```el
(defun my-kill-thing-at-point (thing)
  "Kill the `thing-at-point' for the specified kind of THING."
  (let ((bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point thing)))
    (if bounds
        (kill-region (car bounds) (cdr bounds))
      (error "No %s at point" thing))))

(defun my-kill-word-at-point ()
  "Kill the word at point."
  (interactive)
  (my-kill-thing-at-point 'word))

(global-set-key (kbd "s-k w") 'my-kill-word-at-point)
```

Comment: Which keybinding does `s-k` stands for ?

Comment: Lower-case `s` is the "Super" modifier key.  Obviously people could use whatever key binding was convenient/available on their own system.

Answer (score 25):

The Emacs way to remove the word one is inside of to press <kbd>M-backspace</kbd> followed by <kbd>M-d</kbd>. That will kill the word at point and save it to kill ring (as one unit).

If the cursor is at the beginning or after the end of the word, only one of the two is sufficient. An Emacs user will typically move between words using commands such as `forward-word` (<kbd>M-f</kbd>) and `backward-word` (<kbd>M-b</kbd>), so they will be at the word boundary to begin with and thus rarely need to kill the word from the inside.

Comment: That might kill the previous word as well as the current word (although one might reasonably expect the user to avoid doing that, so long as they are invoking the commands separately).

Comment: @phils Good point, I've now updated the answer to make it explicit. On an aside note, the point of this answer is to explain how an experienced Emacs user would go about doing this, in contrast to other answers that immediately started providing code. It occurred to me that a beginner might not be aware of M-d, or that the word split in two operations will still end up unsplit in the kill ring.

Comment: For those like me who didn't know what does M stands for, `The M stands for the Meta key, which you can emulate on most keyboards by pressing the Esc key`. Source is [here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acqm).

Comment: @jumping_monkey If you're using emacs in a gui window, you can also use the Alt key.

Comment: @user4815162342, din know that, thanks!

Comment: @Paul That is not the case in Emacs. In popular shells like bash, C-w runs backward-kill-word, but M-w is always kill-ring-save.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that by moving to the beginning of the word (if not standing there already) by <kbd>M-b</kbd>, then deleting it with <kbd>M-d</kbd>. You can then press <kbd>C-y</kbd> to put it back. If you want to automate it, you can create a short elisp function and assign it to a key:

```
(global-set-key [24 C-backspace] ; C-x C-backspace
                (lambda () (interactive)
                  (save-excursion
                    (backward-word)
                    (kill-word 1)
                    (yank))))
```

Comment: That might kill the previous word

Comment: <kbd>M-d</kbd> is exactly what I was looking for, thanks